# Why is it printing the addresses and not the values?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
  int value;
  struct node *next;
  struct node *previous;
};

struct list{
  struct node *head;
  struct node *tail;
  struct node *left;
  struct node *right;
  int size;
};

int addAvailableNode(struct list *l){
  struct node new;
  new.value = -1;
  new.next = l->right;
  new.previous = l->right->previous;
  l->right->previous->next = &new;
  l->right->previous = &new;
}

int printNode(struct node *n){
  printf("%d, ",n->value);
}

int printList(struct list *l){

  printf("[");
  printNode(l->head);
  struct node *cur;
  cur = l->head->next;
  while(cur->value != 0){
    printNode(cur);
    cur = cur->next;
  }
  printf("%d]\n",l->tail->value);

}

int main(){
  struct list myList;
  struct node head;
  head.value = 0;
  struct node tail;
  tail.value = 0;

  head.next = &tail;
  tail.previous = &head;

  myList.head = &head;
  myList.tail = &tail;
  myList.left = &head;
  myList.right = &tail;
  int nExtra = 5;

  printList(&myList);

  for(int i = 0; i < nExtra; i++){
    addAvailableNode(&myList);
  }

  printf("finished adding space\n");

  printList(&myList);
}
```

The program is trying to create a doubly linked list, which will eventually have 3 areas for values(between head and left, between left and right and between right and tail. However after adding 5 values to the list(which are place holder values meant to go between left and right) and then printing the list only 2 of the values appear(i believe) and not the actual value but the address of that value. As shown below:

```
[0, 0]
finished adding space
[0, 1238627216, -722138352, 0]
```

the output should look like:

```
[0, 0]
finished adding space
[0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0]
```

Comment: For starters the structure definition struct list{
  struct node *head;
  struct node *tail;
  struct node *left;
  struct node *right;
  int size;
}; does not make a sense. and this function 

int addAvailableNode(struct list *l){
  struct node new;
  new.value = -1;
  new.next = l->right;
  new.previous = l->right->previous;
  l->right->previous->next = &new;
  l->right->previous = &new;
} makes pointers invalid because they point to the local variable new that will not be alive after exiting the function.

Comment: It isn't printing addresses - it is printing random values from uninitialized bits of memory.  When you `int addAvailableNode(struct list *l){ struct node new; ... }` That bit of memory called `new` doesn't exist after the function ends.  Then later the memory that was `new` is used for something else and, finally, you print what is in that spot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least this problem:

**Code fails to allocate data**

Below code saves the address of `struct node new` for later use.  This is *undefined behavior* as `struct node new` is no longer valid memory after the function ends.

```
// BAD
int addAvailableNode(struct list *l){
  struct node new;
  new.value = -1;
  new.next = l->right;
  new.previous = l->right->previous;
  l->right->previous->next = &new;
  l->right->previous = &new;
                                  // new goes away
}
```

Alternative code would allocate memory.  Note: this memory needs to be free'd later on.

```
// Return error flag
int addAvailableNode(struct list *l) {
  struct node *new = malloc(sizeof *new);
  if (new == NULL) {
    return 1;
  }
  new->value = -1;
  new->next = l->right;
  new->previous = l->right->previous;
  l->right->previous->next = new;
  l->right->previous = new;
  return 0;
}
```